# What does UART_RX returns

Tags: c, embedded, uart

I'm using an efm32lg230f256 microcontroller and in its code there is a line which uses `USART_Rx` and it returns:

> 1 2 3 4

but when I look inside of it I can't see how  it retuns `1 2 3 4`. I tried to look in the [data sheet](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/data-sheets/efm32lg-datasheet.pdf) but there are no such names.

What is the logic in this function? And why does it do this?

```
c = USART_Rx(uart);
```

```
uint8_t USART_Rx(USART_TypeDef *usart)
{
    while (!(usart->STATUS & USART_STATUS_RXDATAV))
        ;

    return (uint8_t)usart->RXDATA;
}
```

Comment: It look as though `USART_Rx` waits until the status register indicates that data has been received (by isolating one status bit), and then reads the data from the received data register, which it then returns to the caller.

Comment: Can you give the definition of `c` and the bigger usage of `c`? As it is stated here the function `USART_Rx` only returns a single `uint8_t`, as such I think believe that `USART_Rx` is called in a loop.

Comment: Clearly it returns whatever is in the USART RXDATA register.  If you don't know what the USART RXDATA register is or what it is for, you need to figure that out first, but it would be odd to ask this question if you did not know where this data is coming from, because it is coming from whatever _you_ have connected to the USART RX - it is serial data from an external system (or possibly from a loop back given the reportedly deterministic output).

Comment: You need to use the [_reference manual_](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/reference-manuals/EFM32LG-RM.pdf) rather than the datasheet.  Section 17 in this case and in particular _17.4 Register Map_ `USARTn_RXDATA`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"1 2 3 4" is simply the device password

Answer (score 0):

This is a HAL (Hardware Abstraction Layer).

It is probably defined something like this:

```
typedef struct {
    //other uart registers
    uint8_t STATUS
    //other uart registers
    uint8_t RXDATA
} USART_TypeDef;

#define USART_STATUS_RXDATAV 0b00001000 // or equivalent hex value
```

This struct is a way of interfacing with the memory mapped to the USART peripheral. As such the `USART_TypeDef *usart` pointer points to a piece of memory which is the location of an USART. When it reads `usart->STATUS`, it reads the data in the location pointed to by `usart`, which is the usart `STATUS` register.

The `USART_STATUS_RXDATAV` is a bitmask, this is used to extract only the value of `RXDATAV` which stands for RX DATa AVailable. As such the operation `usart->STATUS & USART_STATUS_RXDATAV` will return a true value only if the bit at position `USART_STATUS_RXDATAV` is `1`. Otherwise this is false. (True and false are 1 and 0 in C generally.)

```
(uint8_t)usart->RXDATA
```

Is reading the data in the `RXDATA` register of that uart. As such it reads the currently received value.

To insure that `RXDATA` contains usefull new data,

```
while (!(usart->STATUS & USART_STATUS_RXDATAV))
    ;
```

is executed. This waits for the UART to have received data available.

The datasheet is often quite useful but if more detailed information is needed then the [reference manual](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/reference-manuals/EFM32LG-RM.pdf#page=447) is the next step. Page 447 is the one about the USART. [Page 474](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/reference-manuals/EFM32LG-RM.pdf#page=474) shows the memory layout of the USART peripheral.